# How to load a local image

Tags: javascript, file, local

I have a temporary issue with loading a local image instead of a remote one. For the remote image, I use the following code:

```
    fetch(url).then(function (response) {
        var blobValue = URL.createObjectURL(response.blob());

        this.changeStyle(blobValue, headerHTML);
    }).then(function (blob) {
        var blobValue = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        this.changeStyle(blobValue, headerHTML);
    })

MainWidget.method('changeStyle', function (blobValue, headerHTML) {
    if (asserts.isValid(headerHTML.childNodes[0].children[2].attributes[4])) {
        headerHTML.childNodes[0].children[2].attributes[4].style =
            'background-image url("' + blobValue + '")';

    }
});
```

However, `fetch()` cannot be used for a local file. How can I load a local file?

Comment: Do you mean a local file url like `file:///C:/files/image.png`? I think you cannot access local files from javaScript due to security reasons, even if you know the absolute path somehow.

Comment: Are you reading the image from localhost or directly from the system? for example, reading like "/home/user/image.png" or "http://localhost/image.png"?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a local object like @xander says. So, I have to wait for next week, as our admin does not want to give me cross-origin rights. I'll see whether the project manager says. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Depending on your browser you might be able to disable the security features locally, with Firefox you can use these user settungs `user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://localhost");
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");` in `about:config` or google the settings above to get more info. If you just need to test something that might work, obviously that's not a good idea for production code :)